# require once - PHP: set_include_path not working

Tags: php, youtube-api, include-path, require-once

I've been trying to fix this for 5 hours now.

This is my current php code.

```
set_include_path("google-api-php-client-master/src/Google");
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
+/test/
    +google-api-php-client-master/
        test.php
```

So the php file is in the same directory as the google api folder. Unfortunately I always get an error:

```
Warning: require_once(Google/Client.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /test/test.php on line 20

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Google/Client.php' (include_path='google-api-php-client/src') in /test/test.php on line 20
```

I have also set the permissions for the file. I am really clueless.

**EDIT:** I've tried some stuff out randomly and this solution worked for me:

```
set_include_path("api/src/");
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend recommends this procedure:

```
defined('BASE_PATH')
    || define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(BASE_PATH . '/Google'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Client.php';
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Where are the files that are missing? Show us a complete treeview, including Client.php and YouTube.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
require_once 'Client.php';
require_once 'Service/YouTube.php';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't help.

Comment: Please show detailed tree structure of your directory

Comment: \test\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php
\test\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\Youtube.php
\test\test.php

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting set_include_path() function - as it worked for me

```
<?php 
    // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
    include_once 'includes/session_manager.php';
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
?>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "commenting" the function? Should i put it in a comment?